# Dangers of Sanke Kegs

Tags: kegging, keg, sanke-keg

I recently told some other brewers how I have used a Sanke keg and they tried to convince me that they were dangerous.

They had heard of the ball being shot up out of the keg when trying to clean the keg.

I have used the keg 3 or 4 times and never thought about that being possible, nor does it make any sense to me.

**I disagree with them but are there any dangers to using Sanke Kegs for homebrew?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have taken apart several sanke kegs to turn them into kettles.
I have used a hammer and a screwdriver most of the time.
There is zero danger of the ball shooting out.  And if it did the spring in there isn't that strong.
Your friends are outright wrong.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I figured, but wanted to make sure I was not missing something.

Comment: The only danger I've ever heard of with Sankeys is using them for boil kettles - some have skirts where the rolled edge is airtight.  When you put it on the burner, it can explode.  [Link to source thread](http://forum.northernbrewer.com/viewtopic.php?t=44238&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0)

Comment: @joefish why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: I didn't think it actually answered the question, since I don't know anything about balls shooting out of the keg :)

Answer (score 1):

The only danger I have heard of, is when the whole key under pressure is placed into the a bonn-fire.  The keg will blow up, but you won't have to worry much about the ball inside, as the shrapnel will have most likely already hit you.